# Content Security Policy (CSP) block eval method call

Tags: javascript, node.js, content-security-policy

I am using `nicEditor` and in `nicEditor` there is a method called `eval` that is blocked by `CSP`. When I comment out the `CSP` code, it's working fine.

```
Error: call to eval() blocked by CSP     nicEdit.js:779:36
```

My CSP code:

```
scriptSrc: ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'"]
```

I also read https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't use `eval()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need to use `nicEditor` which contains `eval` (which is probably not a good idea in the first place), you can add the following directive: [`'unsafe-eval'`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Security/CSP/CSP_policy_directives#Keywords)

I would really, *really*, recommend that you simply use a different editor which doesn't rely on `eval` though. It really is a security risk in most cases.

If you need an alternative, have a look at [ProseMirror](https://prosemirror.net/) for example.

Answer (score 0):

The line in question is in the `addButton` function of the `nicEditorPanel` (line 682 for me):

```
var type = (button['type']) ? eval('(typeof('+button['type']+') == "undefined") ? null : '+button['type']+';') : nicEditorButton;
```

Replace that with this:

```
var type = (button['type']) ? (typeof(button['type']) == "undefined") ? null : window[button['type']] : nicEditorButton;
```

I just ran into this problem making a Google Chrome extension. The Chrome Extensions loader won't allow me to use 'unsafe-eval' in the CSP permissions. Regardless, as said above it's best not to for security reasons. Taking a look at the code it looks like it's using `eval()` to call a constructor based on the name of a String.

Since all global functions are properties of the `window` object, my change calls the name of the constructor in String form (`button['type']`) as a property of window instead of simply evaluating it.